# Numpy notation to replace an enumerate(zip(....))

Tags: python, numpy

I'm starting to use numpy. I get the slice notations and element-wise computations, but I can't understand this:

```
for i, (I,J) in enumerate(zip(data_list[0], data_list[1])):
    joint_hist[int(np.floor(I/self.bin_size))][int(np.floor(J/self.bin_size))] += 1
```

Variables:

- `data_list` contains two `np.array().flatten()` images (eventually more)
- `joint_hist[]` is the joint histogram of those two images, it's displayed later with `plt.imshow()`
- `bin_size` is the number of slots in the histogram

I can't understand why the coordinate in the final histogram is `I,J`. So it's not just that the value at a position in `joint_hist[]` is the result of some slicing/element-wise computation. I need to take the result of that computation and use THAT as the indices in joint_hist...

---

EDIT:

I indeed do not use the `i` in the loop actually - it's a leftover from previous iterations and I simply hadn't noticed I didn't need it anymore

I do want to remain in control of the bin sizes & the details of how this is done, so not particularly looking to use histogramm2D. I will later be using that for further image processing, so I'd rather have the flexibility to adapt my approach than have to figure out if/how to do particular things with built-in functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Your title refers to `enumerate`, but since you never use `i` in the loop, I'd think just dropping it is the best way to improve the code you've shown. It's not clear to me what the text in the body of the question is asking for. Are you just looking for a more `numpy`-natural way to do what the loop does?

Comment: If you don't use `i` in the for-loop then you don't need the `enumerate(...` either, just get rid of it. Don't just copy code that isn't needed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed gussy up that `for` loop using some numpy notation. Assuming you don't actually need `i` (since it isn't used anywhere):

```
for I,J in (data_list.T // self.bin_size).astype(int):
    joint_hist[I, J] += 1
```

### Explanation

`data_list.T` flips `data_list` on its side. Each row of `data_list.T` will contain the data for the pixels at a particular coordinate.

`data_list.T // self.bin_size` will produce the same result as `np.floor(I/self.bin_size)`, only it will operate on all of the pixels at once, instead of one at a time.

`.astype(int)` does the same thing as `int(...)`, but again operates on the entire array instead of a single element.

When you iterate over a 2D array with a `for` loop, the rows are returned one at a time. Thus, the `for I,J in arr` syntax will give you back one pair of pixels at a time, just like your `zip` statement did originally.

### Alternative

You could also just use `histogramdd` to calculate `joint_hist`, in place of your `for` loop. For your application it would look like:

```
import numpy as np

joint_hist,edges = np.histogramdd(data_list.T)
```

This would have different bins than the ones you specified above, though (numpy would determine them automatically).

Comment: Good good. Yeah I did use histrogramdd initially but didn't see how to customize bins. I'll do further image manipulations on this so probably better to have my own implementation.

.T, // and .astype() are exactly what I needed. I was trying to figure things out just with the slicing notations & so but obviously needed more. When you have a hammer everything looks like a nail... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, your goal is to make an histogram or correlated values in your images? Well, to  achieve the right bin index, the computation that you used is not valid. Instead of np.floor(I/self.bin_size), use np.floor(I/(I_max/bin_size)).astype(int). You want to divide I and J by their respective resolution. The result that you will get is a diagonal matrix for joint_hist if both data_list[0] and data_list[1] are the same flattened image.

So all put together:

```
I_max = data_list[0].max()+1
J_max = data_list[1].max()+1
joint_hist = np.zeros((I_max, J_max))
bin_size = 256
for i, (I, J) in enumerate(zip(data_list[0], data_list[1])):
    joint_hist[np.floor(I / (I_max / bin_size)).astype(int), np.floor(J / (J_max / bin_size)).astype(int)] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution - but the point really is to use numpy because I would like to optimize the code. The approach I had works but is not as fast as what I could achieve using proper numpy operations.